# Redirect entire pages on http to https in magento

Tags: php, .htaccess, magento, redirect

I want to redirect my entire pages on https on my magento 1.7.0.2 website. On the admin under System >> Configuration >> Web, under the unsecure tab I set the base url as http://www.xyz.com and under the secure tab its https://www.xyz.com. Also i have set the below field as :

Use Secure URLs in Frontend  : Yes
Use Secure URLs in Admin     : No
Offloader header : SSL_OFFLOADED.

I am not sure whether i need to add any extra code in .htaccess file or not. But by these, still my shows were open with http not https.

And also When i set https under the base url(unsecure), then it working fine. But it redirect to the homepage if we try to open any product page with http.

So please advise if someone can help me out.

Answer (score 1):

It depends on the page you want to make secure. By default Magento redirects to secure only some pages. The ones that required user information (register, login, checkout, contact). If you want to add a custom page read the answers in [this question](https://magento.stackexchange.com/q/5553/146) maybe they help.
If you want all the pages to be on `https` (even if I don't see a point in this) you can set, like you did, the unsecure url in config to `https://www.xyz.com.` and under the same config section (`Web`) under `Url Options` set `Auto-redirect to Base URL` to `No`. Clear the cache and give it an other try.

Comment: Hello Marius, I noticed that using standard magento configuration, both http and https url are reachble and I think this could led to SEO duplicates problems. How to use just http for normal pages like catalog, cms ecc, and https for sensitive pages? thanks

Comment: @AntonioPedicini. If you set the base unsecure url (in system->configuration->web) to start with http and the base secure url to start with https it should work as you want it. Only account pages and checkout will be on https and the rest on http.

Comment: thanks, may I ask you why do you advice to turn off Auto-redirect to Base URL? As per SEO, is not better to set it to 301?

Answer (score 1):

You could also just set unsecure base_url to the HTTPs url

Answer (score 0):

Please follow these below steps :

1- Make sure System > Configuration > Web > url_options > "Auto-redirect to Base URL = No". It was set to "yes", and causing the problem.

2- Put below code in `.htaccess` file.

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP:X-Forwarded-Proto} !https
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule ^ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301,NE]
```